# In unity,How can I access a buttons text that is a child of an object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to access that the text of a clicked button.But ıt always returns the text of first child of gameObject.But I want to access the text of clicked child.

I tried the code below:

```
transform.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Button>().GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text;
```

Comment: Could you show us the complete code? How do you detect the click? You problems seems to be that `GetComponentInChildren` also searches the component on that `GameObject` itself, not only in the children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution:

```
GameObject.Find(EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name).GetComponent<Button>().GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text
```

Thank you to everyone who shared their ideas.

Comment: This will not work when you have multiple buttons with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom class which references the text you care about:

```cs
public class ButtonExtras : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text buttonText; // assign this in the inspector
}
```

then elsewhere:

```cs
GetComponentInChildren<ButtonExtras>().buttonText.text = "hello!";
```

Answer (score 0):

So i assume that your shown line of code is in a script lying on some general object (and not on every single button). So what you could do is to take a button as parameter like this:

```
void HandleText(Button button){
    Text text = button.getComponentInChildren<Text>();
    // do whatever you want to do with the text here
}
```

Then for every button you could add this method to OnClick listernes with the button itself as parameter. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet accesses the **TextMeshPro** component(child) within a **Button**(parent) and retrieves the text it contains.

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro; //add this

public class LabelToggle: MonoBehaviour {

    private void Start() {
        toggleButton = GetComponent < Button > ();
        print(toggleButton.GetComponentInChildren < TMP_Text > ().text);
    }
}
```